# incorporating string into the when contidtion in xsl

Tags: xslt

I am  trying to incorporate string into the when condition, but it does not work.

I have tried this:

```
<xsl:text>Salary:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="z:SalaryRecord">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="z:SalaryRecord = 'agreement'">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#09;',position(),'&#09;',z:Type,'&#10;')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#09;',position(),'&#09;','&#09;',z:Type,'(','from ',z:AmountFrom, ' to ',z:AmountTo,')','&#10;')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and this:

```
<xsl:when test="z:SalaryRecord::text() = 'agreement'">
```

and this

```
<xsl:when test="z:SalaryRecord == 'agreement'">
```

My XML source code:

```
<RequiredSalary>
   <SalaryRecord>
    <Type>monthly</Type>
    <AmountFrom>1000</AmountFrom>
    <AmountTo>2000</AmountTo>
  </SalaryRecord>
  <SalaryRecord>
   <Type>agreement</Type>
  </SalaryRecord>
</RequiredSalary>
```

Any idea pls?

thanks

Comment: What does your source XML look like?

Comment: zx485, I have updated the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fix to your situation may be the following template. However, you'd have to define a namespace for the `z` prefix in your stylesheet. Try adding `xmlns:z="http://whatever.is.your.namespace"` to your XSLT stylesheet element.

```
<xsl:template match="z:RequiredSalary">
    <xsl:for-each select="z:SalaryRecord">
        <xsl:text>Salary:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="z:Type = 'agreement'">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#09;',position(),'&#09;',z:Type,'&#10;')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#09;',position(),'&#09;','&#09;',z:Type,'(','from ',z:AmountFrom, ' to ',z:AmountTo,')','&#10;')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
</xsl:template>
```